# Checking the correct params are passed in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am using Phoenix as a basic JSON api but I'm having some issues working out how to check that the requester has passed in the correct arguments.

Say the user makes a post request that requires the following body:

```
{
  "user": {
    "email": "someone@example.com",
    "password": "mangoes"
  }
}
```

I want to check that the user has passed in an email and password in the user object. At the moment I'm doing something like this in my controller actions:

```
params[user][email] and params[user][password]
```

Surely there is a better way to check for the correct parameters. Maybe something to do with `scrub_params`? If so how do I return a nice JSON error message instead of the default `Internal server error`?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check it in the parameter in the action itself

```
  def show(conn, %{"user" => %{"email" => email, "password" => password}} = params) do
    render conn, "show.html", messenger: messenger
  end
```

For an example on this approach, head to the [offical docs here](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/adding-pages#section-a-new-action)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The only problem I have with this method is I need the full params map to hand off to my authentication libraries login_user function so individual values ins't so useful. Any suggestions?

Comment: the map is still inside the params variable, you can get any value you wanted from params inside the controller action. This is because we used variable `params` in the pattern match. `%{"user" => %{"email" => email, "password" => password}} = params`

Comment: Ahh true! Thanks for your help!